# Get-PnPSiteDesign and Get-SPOSiteDesign returning blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Neither **Get-PnPSiteDesign** nor **Get-SPOSiteDesign** returning any site designs. I can see the OOB site designs on the UI and able to apply also successfully. Why PowerShell commands are not returning any data? Am I missing something?

Comment: These both the command will return templates which is registered in the tenant (Custom design template not OOTB Template). What do you exactly want to do? do you want to create site from OOTB site designs?

Comment: I want to update an existing subsite's design with OOTB template through PowerShell